# Unorder list mix up in coding?

Tags: css, html-lists

Something is definetly wrong with my ul and li. I know I made a huge mistake but I cannot find it. When you go here:
http://icpy.webs.com/text/Mass.htm
You will see both thumbnail images are different but both pop ups have the same bigger image as the first thumbnail.

Comment: Both a the images are associated with one `li`. So, they are linking to the same JS / iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it's like that, because both boxes are within the same `<a>`-Tag, which of course links to only one of the big images:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="Mass Sale layouts" href="#inlineframe">
  <img src="http://dgamerhelp.webs.com/soccer/layouts/BEA01.png"/>
  <div id="inlineframe" style="width: 1040px; height: 785px; display: none;">
  </div>
</a>
<a class="fancybox" title="Mass Sale layouts" href="#inlineframe">
  <img src="http://dgamerhelp.webs.com/soccer/layouts/JAK01.png"/>
  <div id="inlineframe" style="width:1040px;height:785px;display: none;">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: @Eliana Diaz: Well, yes of course there is "something" messing the layout up. First of all, you have two divs in one link, then, you never close those divs and third: You never even close the body of the html-page. I edited my answer a little bit. It SHOULD work, but right now I only get two empty pages on your provided site when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are these before doctype? What are those custom elements?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="../text/aboutleft.css">

<img src="http://icpy.webs.com/content/masslayout.png"/><br>
____________________________________________________________________________<br><br>

<x><re>colors available</re></x><br>
<x><gre>available to unlimited users </gre></x><br>
<x>Changes available: box, link, username</x><br><br>
```

Why don't you use a relative link for the masslayout.png?
Have you ever heard of the [`<hr>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/hr) element in HTML?

I don't see any thumbnails, neither popups and I don't know what you are talking about.

jQuery is stored on Google and it is in cache for most of the users. Why do you store and link another one?

Your CSS:

```
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }

    body {
        max-width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
                    #cas ul {
                           list-style-type: none;
                    }
    }
```

What is this?? What did you want?

```
<a class="fancybox" title="Mass Sale layouts" href="#inlineframe>
```

Href attribute needs a close quote mark.

Look at your source code and after that into the inspector and please correct as many errors as you can.